# 438 error VBA excel scraping from hyperlinks

Tags: excel, web-scraping, vba

I have the below code, as I am trying to scrape the text from some webpages. Currently I have the excel set up such that I put in a hyperlink in column A, and it cycles through and pulls all the text from the web page into excel. However, I keep getting a

> 438 error

on the `ie.document.body.innertext` line.

Does anyone know why this may be happening? I have searched around a fair bit, but I have not had much success as it seems this is a fairly common problem but with many different causes. Any help would be greatly appreciated, and apologies in advance for anything obvious, as I am rather new to VBA.

```
Sub Sample()
Dim ie As Object
Dim retStr As String
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim rCell As Range
Dim rRng As Range

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

'Ctrl + Shift + End
LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")


Set rRng = Sheet1.Range("A1:A" & LastRow)

For Each rCell In rRng.Cells

        With ie
            .Navigate rCell.Value
            .Visible = True
        End With

        Do While ie.readystate <> 4: Wait 5: Loop
        DoEvents

        rCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = ie.document.body.innerText
Next rCell

End Sub

Private Sub Wait(ByVal nSec As Long)
nSec = nSec + Timer
While nSec > Timer
    DoEvents
Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Why did you add this `web-scraping` tag in your post? I can't see any `URL` within your script really.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need the IE to do the job? Maybe better try HTTP request?

```
Dim xHttp As MSXML2.XMLHTTP
Dim hDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

Set rRng = Sheet1.Range("A1:A" & LastRow)

For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
    Set xHttp = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
    xHttp.Open "GET", rCell.Value
    xHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    xHttp.send

    Do Until xHttp.READYSTATE = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    If xHttp.Status = 200 Then
        rCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = xHttp.responseText
    End If
Next rCell
```

Comment: This line `Do Until xHttp.READYSTATE = 4 : DoEvents : Loop` doesn't make any sense when you send any request using `xmlhttp`.

Comment: Thank you!. Is there something I need to preface this with? I keep getting a user type not defined error. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Add reference to `Microsoft XML, V6.0` before running the script.